# Should I be worried about these temperatures (Australian hot weather)

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature

I've got a relatively old PC with some new SDDs and HDDs added recently. 
The weather in Western Australia has been hot recently, with temperatures in the high 30s-low 40s (Centigrade).

I could hear my fan running pretty hard today and decided to install CPUID and check out the temps, but I'm not so good at interpreting the information. So I was wondering if someone would be able to help me interpret the information.

Furthermore, if these temperatures are too hot, what can/should I do to correct it?

Drives

[image: Drives temp]

CPU

[image: CPU temp]

Board and Fans

[image: MB temp and Fans]

Comment: I'm going to suggest you include the temps as text in your post;  many people will be reluctant to click on such links.  It's just a few lines.  Also if you want to talk about CPU temps, you have to include the type of CPU as max and typical temps vary with the specific CPU type.

Comment: How on earth are you getting your hard drive temperatures *below* ambient? (assuming you took the above readings during one of them hot days?) ;-)

Comment: In any case those CPU temperatures are stupidly high. You CPU package is 24C higher than the maximum 72.6C Intel specifies. That's nuts!

Answer (score 1):

Your hard disks are fine, they're between 82-96F (28-36C).

The CPU cores in your Intel i5 2500K however are running hot at 200-206F (94-97C). Whether it's "far too hot" or just "quite hot" depends largely on whether these measurements were done after some CPU-intensive work (video rendering, heavy gaming, large file (un)packing operations...) or after a period of idling. But it sure is hot. Here in Sydney my CPU gets between 30C idle and 45C load. It's an i5 4460 @ 3.20GHz with stock cooler and no overclocking.

Ok, the Sydney weather doesn't often go up to 40 but but it can get up to medium to high 30's here as well :) And I normally leave my PC running in an unairco'd room with a window for extended periods.

Did an amateur install the CPU and the cooler? If so, he/she may have forgotten (or applied incorrectly) the paste that goes between the cooler and CPU. Common mistake.

So... What to do? Couple of things you can look at/do:

- Distinguish between temps under full load and temps under "idling". Update your question with your findings.
- If you have it set to overclocked speeds, tune it down immediately and see if it improves.
- Check your power settings and make sure the CPU cooling can go all-out. See if it improves.
- With your system turned off, look at the cooler. If it's dusty or dirty (do you happen to smoke in the same room?), that's often the problem. See if you can pluck some dust out easily. Don't touch the actual fan itself because it's tender, just from between the radiator ribs, see if it improves.
- Check the airflow inside your computer. Shouldn't be too bad, because your hard disks are fine. It's mostly your CPU, judging from the picture. A good airflow can help though. Do you have case fans installed? Are they actually working? If the computer is in an enclosed space, take it out. Take the side panel off, point a table fan at it, run again, see if it improves. If CPU temps go down like 10-20 degrees, it's the airflow. If it doesn't, it's the CPU/cooler combination.

If it looks to be your CPU/cooler themselves (and not the power settings, airflow or overclocking), consider a new cooler. They're not that expensive (certainly cheaper than a new CPU and motherboard) and are not hard to install. Just take your PC to the shop and they might do it while you wait if you call ahead. Couple of minutes of work.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No need to worry about the temperatures which you are currently getting except for CPU as you are saying that The weather in Western Australia has been hot recently, with temperatures in the high 30s-low 40s (Centigrade).

And these temperatures usually I used to get and are normal for us Indians.

But your CPU temperature seems to me very high Do following steps to verify that everything is working fine.

> 1> Check your fan, Is that Connected and fitted correctly on your CPU.
>
> 2> Verify and try Changing the Heat sink ( A paste which is pasted on the CPU) If Its feeling like powder then you must change it.
>
> 3> Not required but good to use add few exhaust chassis fans.

[Click here for other suggestions](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/334180-28-intel-core-2500k-safe-temp-speeds)